# Bubble Sort working, but switching back the first 2 numbers, and only with certain numbers

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

This may be the weirdest problem I've ever seen, when I set the object at index 3 (the 4th object) to 5, the bubble sort algorithm seems to have problems, but when I set it to 12, the problem goes away, even though both 12 and 5 are lower numbers than both the numbers at index 2 and 4 (the numbers before and after 5/12) Here's the code, and here's the output:

```
array_to_sort = [10, 5, 13, 5, 42]
should_stop = False
print(array_to_sort)
while should_stop == False:
    should_stop = True
    index = 1
    for back_number in array_to_sort:
        print(array_to_sort)
        front_number = array_to_sort[index]
        if back_number > front_number:
            array_to_sort.remove(back_number)
            array_to_sort.remove(front_number)
            array_to_sort.insert(index - 1, front_number)
            array_to_sort.insert(index, back_number)
            should_stop = False
        if index + 1 < len(array_to_sort):
            index += 1
```

(obviously not all the output):

[10, 5, 13, 5, 42]

[10, 5, 13, 5, 42]

[5, 10, 13, 5, 42]

[5, 10, 13, 5, 42]

[10, 5, 5, 13, 42]

[10, 5, 5, 13, 42]

---

---

However, it does eventually get fully sorted

Then with the same code, but if I set the array to this:

array_to_sort = [10, 5, 13, 12, 42]

The output becomes what would be expected:

[10, 5, 13, 12, 42]

[10, 5, 13, 12, 42]

[5, 10, 13, 12, 42]

[5, 10, 13, 12, 42]

[5, 10, 12, 13, 42]

[5, 10, 12, 13, 42]

PS: I know this is definitely not the best way to do bubble sort, I'm just starting with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen any time there are duplicates in your list. `list.remove` removes the first instance of the object being removed. So when you try to remove the second `5` at index 3, you're actually removing the `5` at index 1.

Solution? Don't use `list.remove` in this scenario. Just swap the two values. This will be easiest if you use a loop over a `range`.

```
for back_number in range(len(array_to_sort)-1):
        print(array_to_sort)
        front_number = array_to_sort[back_number+1]
        if array_to_sort[back_number] > array_to_sort[front_number]:
            array_to_sort[front_number],array_to_sort[back_number] = array_to_sort[back_number], array_to_sort[front_number]
            should_stop = False
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped out!

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez Glad I could help! If you found it helpful, you can accept the answer so future readers will know that this solved the problem.